# EXCEL VBA: Mapping of data is too slow

Tags: excel, vba, mapping

I am running sub where it compares two cells (B and D/or string Received) from one sheet ("DATA") with two cells (C, H) from another sheet ("Incoming_report"), and if they match it transposes I, G cells from Incoming to Data.

It is done by combining two cells from Incoming_report sheet and writing new value in Z column for example "123456" from C and H to f.e. "123456Received" (there another 5 statuses (Received, Rejected, Sent...., but I need the ones only that was **Received**)

Then I am taking from Data Sheet B column for example 123456 and **only Received** (there might be another 5 statuses, but I only need the **one that was received**).

That makes all sence to me and works pretty good, but I have to work with more than 500k rows in each sheet. What happens - 500,000 times two cells are combined and searched in Z column in another sheet among another 500,000 for possible match, if nothing found then N/A, and then 2 combination, 3rd, 4th... till 500,000. I added the Display status bar and I see how slowly it goes (only 900 rows per minute, so for one minor mapping it would take more than 10 hours). Here is the sub itself, can anyone share ideas how to improve it to make it work faster? Thanks a million.

```
Sub incoming_fetch()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim incr As Long
Dim x As String
n = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Z = Sheets("Incoming_report").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i2 = 2 To Z
   Sheets("Incoming_report").Range("Z" & i2).Value = Sheets("Incoming_report").Range("C" & i2).Value & Sheets("Incoming_report").Range("H" & i2).Value
Next i2
For i = 3 To n
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = i
 x = Sheets("Data").Range("B" & i).Value & "Received"
 If Sheets("Incoming_report").Range("Z:Z").Find(x, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas) Is Nothing Then
   Sheets("Data").Range("L" & i) = "N/A"
   Sheets("Data").Range("M" & i) = "N/A"
 Else
   incr = Sheets("Incoming_report").Range("Z:Z").Find(x, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Row
   Sheets("DATA").Range("L" & i) = Sheets("Incoming_report").Range("I" & incr)
   Sheets("DATA").Range("M" & i) = Sheets("Incoming_report").Range("G" & incr)
 End If
 Next i
 End Sub
```

Comment: Will there be only one possible match for the value being passed to `Find()` ?

Comment: Hello Tim, yes it looks for equals to equals. I believe that there's a problem in Find, because, I tried to disable all other actions and speed does not change (I have two similar subs with same issue - lots of values being searched in massive volume of values. I dont know any other way to find for exact value, but I believe there should be some alternatives for Find xlwhole xlformulas sentence that would work faster like 50x times

Comment: Any function or formula that would find one possible match and return the row number where the match is found (as I need some data from that row to be coppied) will work for me, however I dont know which one is the best for me as I have huge volumes of data. I now clearly see that the problem is with "Find" it finds to slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT2:** fixed source columns :

```
Sub incoming_fetch()

    Dim i As Long, n As Long, z As Long, num As Long
    Dim x As String
    Dim shtIn As Worksheet, shtData As Worksheet
    Dim dict As Object, arrC, arrH, arrG, arrI, v, arr, r1, r2
    Dim t

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    Set shtIn = Sheets("Incoming_report")
    Set shtData = Sheets("Data")

    n = shtData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    z = shtIn.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    t = Timer

    'get all values from Cols C, H, L, M
    arrC = shtIn.Range(shtIn.Range("C2"), shtIn.Range("C" & z)).Value
    arrH = shtIn.Range(shtIn.Range("H2"), shtIn.Range("H" & z)).Value
    arrG = shtIn.Range(shtIn.Range("G2"), shtIn.Range("G" & z)).Value
    arrI = shtIn.Range(shtIn.Range("I2"), shtIn.Range("I" & z)).Value

    Debug.Print "Get Arrays: " & Timer - t
    t = Timer

    'create a lookup dictionary of all the ColC values
    '  (where ColH = "Received")
    num = UBound(arrC, 1)
    For i = 1 To num
        v = arrC(i, 1)
        If arrH(i, 1) = "Received" And Len(v) > 0 Then
            dict(v) = Array(arrI(i, 1), arrG(i, 1))
        End If
    Next i
    'free up some memory
    Erase arrC: Erase arrH: Erase arrI: Erase arrG

    Debug.Print "Filled dict: " & Timer - t
    t = Timer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    On Error GoTo haveError

    For i = 3 To n

        If i Mod 500 = 0 Then Application.StatusBar = i
        x = shtData.Range("B" & i).Value

        If dict.exists(x) Then
            arr = dict(x)
            r1 = arr(0)
            r2 = arr(1)
        Else
            r1 = "N/A": r2 = "N/A"
        End If

        With shtData
            .Range("L" & i) = r1 
            .Range("M" & i) = r2 
        End With
    Next i

    Debug.Print "Done: " & Timer - t

haveError:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Tim, thanks for your efforts as I understand it works with memory instead of the excel cells itself right?

Comment: Yes - you get the best speed-ups when you avoid making a lot of small changes on the sheet, or reading cell values one-by-one.  In my testing it took about 12-13sec for 100k rows on each sheet.

Comment: For me it returned all N/A values. Can you please adjust it to match my Data? I will start from new perspective as this differs from my previous code: from Data sheet I need only "B" (8 digit number), I need to find the same 8 digit number in "Incoming_report" in column "C" (there will be up to 10 matches or 0 if it is not in report (then N/A)) and only 
"Received" in column "H" (it narrows only to one match, because it could be **received only once**), then from this row (Incoming_report) transpose "I" to **Data "L"** and "G" to **Data "M"**.

Comment: Did you use the version of the code above?  I made some edits after actually testing.

Comment: Yes I have tried it just now, still got all N/A. See above my comment, I tried to simplify all the data, it is actually just search for the same value, then find the right word in other column, and return two cells from that row to Data sheet.
Also Data sheets L and M fields are blank before the values will be pasted, but I see macro is getting values from them, is this ok? Also I cant describe how thankful I am, need to do it overnight before work, 3am here :)

Comment: Sorry - missed it was not L and M in the Incoming sheet. See edit.

Comment: Still N/A, I will send you like in an hour, thanks a million!